# Recently updated PHP 5.4 from 5.3 crashing when using variable equal to conditional shortcut

Tags: php, apache2

I am using Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.4.

I am executing the following:

```
# retrieve caller name
$calledby = debug_backtrace(); print_r($calledby);
$caller = (strlen($calledby[1]['class'])) ? $calledby[1]['class'] : $calledby[0]['class'];
# arguments are required
if (!func_num_args()) { return; }
# fill variables with argument contents if exists
$variables = (func_num_args() == 0) ? NULL : (is_array(func_get_arg(0)) ? func_get_arg(0) : NULL);
```

from within a private method of a class.

If I comment out the $caller = and $variables = lines then it works.

If I change my code to the following it also works (AS DEFINED)

```
if (strlen($calledby[1]['class']))  $caller = $calledby[1]['class'];
else                                $caller = $calledby[0]['class'];
```

Should I place a bug report or am I doing something wrong with a new 5.4 syntax quirk?

Thanks In Advance!

[UPDATE] I executed the file using the CLI and the script produced the desired result.

Comment: If PHP crashes (SIGSEGV), it's always a bug.

Comment: Execute the file using commandline (php yourscript.php), and see if there's an issue (such as a SIGSEGV). If so, you've stumbled on a bug. If not, you should get an error.

Comment: I just did that actually. There isn't an error at all when executing using the CLI. I get the expected result.

Comment: errr.... scratch that. From what I can see the script is not executing the class method.

Comment: Executing the following does not show the results of the method call in my constructor
in the a class, which should output "Here I am!"

echo "Hello World";

$goal = (!isset($_SERVER["R_xsq"])) ? "yes" : "no";

echo $goal;

// require infinity
require("C:/Infinity/application/shared/classes/a.php");
$x = new a();

Answer (score 0):

I have try with php 5.4 config and have no problem
You should see the apache / php log

Comment: Thanks but there is no log output.

Comment: After performing some test.

Apparently any Ternary condition results in a segfault on this particular setup.

$ix = 0;
$ix = (!$ix) ? 10 : $ix;

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Windows Error Reporting
Date:          5/3/2012 6:39:22 PM
Event ID:      1001
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Alex-PC
Description:
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: httpd.exe
P2: 2.4.2.0
P3: 4f913756
P4: php5ts.dll
P5: 5.4.1.0
P6: 4f9864a9
P7: c0000005
P8: 002c7a90
P9: